# Tourist visa with cancelled old passport and have renewed passport in hand

Tags: visas, uae, passport-renewals

I got a tourist visa for UAE with my old passport number which was renewed on January 2015.

I got the new passport with new number and in the last page old passport number also mentioned. Can I travel to UAE with this visa by keeping both passports?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. this is absolutely normal although I have only done it with a USA visa but that's how you do this: keep the expired passport, typically it's invalidated by punching two holes through the identification page but otherwise it's still usable. Present both passports at the border and that's it.

Comment: Every country has its own rules, so what works with the USA doesn't necessarily work with other countries.